# How to set headers from bean integration method call in a camel route

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

Help needed on setting headers based on the method call from bean integration.
within my application I am using a custom POJO and there are before I actually send the message over the wire I want to do set the headers on the exchange, but don't want to do it within my bean and rather do it where my spring DSL is written for the route. 
I know that usually the value returned from method is sent as body for the message to the next the endpoint but i want to send values returned as header.
I have attached a sample of my route needs to be, and want:

```
<route id="someRoute">
<from ref="InboundAsyncEndpoint" />
<to  uri="bean:validatorBean?method=validateMessageInternals(MyCostomMessagePojo obj)" />
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>
            ${body.getMetaData().getFinalDestinationName()} == 'AMQEndpoint'
        </simple>
        <to uri="bean:payloadAndHeaderExtractor?extractHeader(MyCostomMessagePojo obj)" /> 
        <to uri="bean:payloadAndHeaderExtractor?extractPayload(MyCostomMessagePojo obj)" /> <!-- i want the headers being set on the exchange from the map that is returnd from the previous bean and method -->
        <to uri="activemq:someQueue"
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        ...
        ...
    </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the following way:

```
<setHeader headerName="YOUR_HEADER">
     <simple>bean:payloadAndHeaderExtractor?extractHeader(MyCostomMessagePojo obj)</simple>
</setHeader>
```

Hope this helps.

R.